# New formula like Stirling formula for product of Gamma function :$ \left(x!\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)!$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

Inspired by a problem of my book wich is :

Let $0<x$ then we have :

$$f(x)=\left(x!\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)!\geq 1$$

I have tried several function (log,LambertW,$x^a/x+1$,...) but now I found it

I have tried to find a Stirling Formula for $f(x)$ and accordingly to Wolfram alpha we have :

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x!\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)!\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\left(e^{-1}x+\sinh^{-1}\left(x\right)e^{-\left(1+\ln\left(2\right)\right)}+\frac{\ln\left(\pi\right)}{2e}\right)=0$$

Where $\sinh^{-1}$ is the inverse function of the more common $\sinh(x)$ e.g $$\sinh^{-1}(\sinh(x))=x$$

I have some questions :

1.How to check the limit ?

2.Is it new or just trivial ?

3.Have you any reference ?

5.Can we add some other term like in a power series ?

6.Is it better than the Stirling formula ?

Thanks !

Ps:I don't want to show the first inequality I just speak about a possible new Stirling formula for this product .

Comment: What is the book? (+5 questions all in one is generally discouraged)

Comment: I also don’t see why this asymptotic limit identity should prove the inequality

Comment: @FShrike Dictionnary of Inequalities Second edition by Prof Peter Bullen

Comment: @Fshrike No there is no link in this sense it's just another statement .

Comment: When you said “now I found it”, I presumed you had a solution to the inequality. Do you? If so, I’m not sure why it is even in the question.

Comment: @FShrike I tried some other function like here simply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525217/find-a-such-that-the-limit-is-zero

Comment: Note that $\sinh^{-1}(x)=\log(x)+\log(2)+O(1/x^2)$ as $x\to\infty$. Worlfram alpha sometimes does sometimes does some weird stuff, and it may be more natural to substitute in $\log(x)+\log(2)$ for $\sinh^{-1}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large values of $x$ $$F=\frac 1 x \log\Bigg[\left(x!\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)!\Bigg]=\log(x)-1+\frac {\log(2 x)+\log(\pi)}{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ is a very good approximation even for small values of $x$.

On the other side,

$$G=\log\left(e^{-1}x+\sinh^{-1}\left(x\right)e^{-\left(1+\log
\left(2\right)\right)}+\frac{\ln\left(\pi\right)}{2e}\right)=\log(x)-1+\frac{\log(2x)+2e \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2 e}\right)}{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

$$F-G=\frac{\log(\pi)-2e \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2 e}\right) }{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Computing exactly for $x=123$, $F=3.839184921$, $G=3.822391606$ then $F-G=0.016793$  while the above gives $F-G=0.016773$

**Edit**

A more detailed expansion of $F$ is
$$F=\log \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)+\frac {\log(2 \pi x)}{2x}-\frac{12\gamma-1}{12x^2}+\frac {\pi^2}{12x^3}-\frac{120\zeta(3)+1}{360x^4}+\frac {\pi^4}{360x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I put here a refinement of the well-know Stirling's approximation :

For $0<x$ we have :

$$-\frac{\left|\left(e^{-1}x+\left(\sinh^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)e^{-\left(1+\ln\left(2\right)\right)}+\frac{\ln\left(\pi\right)}{2e}\right)^{x}-x!\right|}{e^{\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{x}}}>\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x}-x!$$

For a reference see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation